# Python print output as JSON

Tags: python, json

My python script generates the output in below format,

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

for d in json_data:
    print(d['name'])
```

Output:

```
Android
iPhone
Microsoft
```

How can print it as json like below

Expected output:

```
["Android"]
["iPhone"]
["Microsoft"]
```

Comment: you are printing just like every item is in list. Use `print(list(d['name']))`

Comment: Maybe you should give a more complex example of what you're trying to achieve. In this case you're inviting poor responses.

Comment: `print([d['name']])`? Not a very sensible way of doing it, but I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @stael Thanks, that works. Honestly, that is the actual requirement I have. I was using Python request to get data from a system using API and export to another using API (which only accepts data in list format). This solved my issue.

Comment: @Karthik glad to help I guess..

Comment: @Stael Is there a way to convert it into list format like ["Android","iPhone","Microsoft"] ?

Comment: @Karthik I'll add something to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking but... this will do what you want:

```
print("[\"%s\"]" % d['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to output in json format, and you are already using the `json` module you probably want to use `json.dumps(data)`. More documentation on that [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Obviously you will first need to format your data into the type you want to output, whether that is a list, dict or combination of the two.

For example if you want a list of values you can create that in python using either:

```
my_list = []
for d in json_data:
    mylist.append(d['name'])
```

or, more directly:

```
my_list = [d['name'] for d in json_data]
```

after if you still need the output as a json, you can use

```
print json.dumps(my_list) # or write to file or send to api or whatever.
```